# Rails 3 devise + google authenticator?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, google-authenticator

I'm trying to integrate the Google Authenticator OATH (*not OAuth*) one-time password authentication with devise, but can't find any pointers on whether it's already done or how to proceed. (Plenty of tips on how to make it work with OAuth. Which is something completely different.)

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a beta gem that I've been working on that might help:

https://rubygems.org/gems/devise_google_authenticator